# processes don't join in multiprocessing python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have my simplified code which runs completely till the end and will join process normally, and I have substituted with simpler parts in order to lower your confusion:

```
import math
import os
import numpy as np
import time
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
import csv

def subu(remo,queue):
    remlist=[[remo,4.6*remo,4.7*remo],[7.4*remo,6.5*remo,8.1*remo]]
    queue.put(remlist)
    return #remlist
thread_num=10



stime=time.perf_counter()
processes=[]
if __name__=="__main__":
    q=Queue()
    for i in range(thread_num): 
        proc=Process(target=subu,args=(i,q))
        proc.start()
        processes.append(proc)
    print('afterstart')
    for proc in processes: 
        proc.join()
    lastlist=[]
    print('afterjoin')
    while not q.empty():
        print('inqnotemp')
#         time.sleep(10)
        for _ in range(thread_num):
            lastlist.append(q.get())
            time.sleep(.1)
    with open(f'lastlist.csv',"w",newline="") as f:
        cw = csv.writer(f)
        cw.writerows(r+[""] for r in lastlist)    

    ftime=time.perf_counter()
    print(f'total process in{ftime-stime}s finished')
    input()
```

but the code below which my main code doesn't join processes, the code is ok except it does not join processes:

```
import math
import os
import numpy as np
import time
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
import csv
def dadesazlistfake11(dlist):
    zlist=[]
    for _ in range(11):
        for i in range(len(dlist[575])):
            zlist.append(dlist[575][i])
        for j in range(len(columha[0])):
            if(j%2==0):
                zlist.append(max(dlist[i][1] for i in range(575+columha[2][j] ,575+ columha[3][j]+1)))
            if(j%2==1):
                zlist.append(min(dlist[i][2] for i in range(575+columha[2][j] ,575+ columha[3][j]+1)))
    return zlist
def subu(remo,slist,queue):
    rawlist=[]
    remlist=[]
    periodend=len(slist)-24
    for l in range(575,periodend):
        remlist.append(dadesazlistfake11(slist[l-575:l+25]))
        if (l-576)%10==0:
            print(f'{remo,l-576}')
            ftime=time.perf_counter()
            print(f'in{ftime-stime}s finished')
    queue.put(remlist)
    return #remlist
```

and the rest of code is like:

```
def splito(a,b,c,d,e):
    #bazehaye entehaei nemikhahim tu loop bashan
    period=np.zeros(e+1).astype(int)
    period[0]= a+c-1 #575
    period[e]= b-d-1 #489688
    delta=int(math.floor((period[e]-period[0])/e))
    for i in range(1,e):
        period[i]=period[0]+i*delta
    return period
thread_num=10
rawlist=np.arange(800*5).reshape(-1,5)
rawlist=list(rawlist)
colnamesdropped=['datetime','start','15m1high','15m1low','end']
times=[['15m','30m','1H','6H','1d'],[1,2,4,24,96]]
nexttimes=[['1H','6H'],[4,24]]
columha=[[],[],[],[]]
s=0
l=0
for j in range(0,len(times[0])):    
    for k in range(1,7):
        columha[0].append(s+6)
        columha[1]=1 
        columha[2].append(-(k-1)*times[1][j]-times[1][j]+1)
        columha[3].append(-(k-1)*times[1][j])
        s=s+1
        columha[0].append(s+6)
        columha[1]=1 
        columha[2].append(-(k-1)*times[1][j]-times[1][j]+1)
        columha[3].append(-(k-1)*times[1][j])
        s=s+1
for j in range(0,len(nexttimes[0])):    
    if j==0:
        for k in range(1,7):
            columha[0].append(s+6)
            columha[1]=1
            columha[2].append( +1+(k-1)*nexttimes[1][j])
            columha[3].append( +1+(k-1)*nexttimes[1][j]+nexttimes[1][j]-1)
            s=s+1
            columha[0].append(s+6)
            columha[1]=1
            columha[2].append( +1+(k-1)*nexttimes[1][j])
            columha[3].append( +1+(k-1)*nexttimes[1][j]+nexttimes[1][j]-1)
            s=s+1

    elif j==1:
        k=1
        columha[0].append(s+6)
        columha[1]=1
        columha[2].append( +1+(k-1)*nexttimes[1][j])
        columha[3].append( +1+(k-1)*nexttimes[1][j]+nexttimes[1][j]-1)
        s=s+1
        columha[0].append(s+6)
        columha[1]=1
        columha[2].append( +1+(k-1)*nexttimes[1][j])
        columha[3].append( +1+(k-1)*nexttimes[1][j]+nexttimes[1][j]-1)
        s=s+1
```

and this final part of main code:

```
period=splito(0,len(rawlist),96*6,24,thread_num)
tupleinput=[tuple([i,rawlist[period[i]-575:period[i+1]+24]]) for i in range(thread_num)]
stime=time.perf_counter()
processes=[]
if __name__=="__main__":
    q=Queue()
    for i in range(thread_num): 
        proc=Process(target=subu,args=(tupleinput[i][0],tupleinput[i][1],q))
        proc.start()
        processes.append(proc)
#     rawlist=[]
#     time.sleep(0.1)
    print('afterstart')
    for proc in processes: 
        proc.join()
#     print('',)
    lastlist=[]
    print('afterjoin')
    while not q.empty():
        print('inqnotemp')
#         time.sleep(10)
        for _ in range(thread_num):
            lastlist.append(q.get())
    with open(f'lastlist.csv',"w",newline="") as f:
        cw = csv.writer(f)
        cw.writerows(r+[""] for r in lastlist)    
    ftime=time.perf_counter()
    print(f'total process in{ftime-stime}s finished')
    input()
```

what's problem?I'm using windows and pyhton 3.8 and by running .py saved file.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, `Process.join()` waits for the process to finish before terminating it. If you want to abruptly stop the process do `Process.terminate()`

Comment: no I wanna wait till the end of process, don't wanna brute force it to finish

Comment: Then calling `join()` will have no effect if the process is non-daemonic. `.join()` means "wait for the process to finish" and is called automaticly on all non-daemonic processes. Your code is running fine, the only "problem" probably was the misunderstanding of the `.join()` method use. Otherwise, do the processes not joining cause any problem?

Comment: 1)so why on my first code (simple version) works well? 2) what should I do?